# "you are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors." error displayed in slave while executing selenium script

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am executing selenium scripts in slave machine using Jenkins where I am getting below error.

> "you are using an unsupported command-line flag:
>   --ignore-certificate-errors."

Same scripts are working fine on my local using same chromedriver.exe file. Please note that I have placed chromedriver.exe file in a seperate folder from where script is launching it.

```
Chrome Version:59.0.3071.115
Selenium Version:2.52.0
```

Comment: Is the chrome version on your local also the same? Also post your code used launching the driver

Comment: Yes Chrome version on my local is same. PFB the code.                  
  
   
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", strChromeDriverPath);
   TestReport.addStep(tc, "Set ChromeDriver", "Setting ChromeDriver object", "ChromeDriver Set", "ChromeDriver Set", "");
   return new ChromeDriver();

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--test-type");// this is the one that helped
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

This resolved similar issue

Answer (score 0):

`--disable-infobars` seems not to be working as well

As of 2022, what your looking for is `CommandLineFlagSecurityWarningsEnabled`

On Debian, you can create a managed policy via the following command:

```
mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed && echo '{"CommandLineFlagSecurityWarningsEnabled":false}' >> /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/managed_policies.json
```